# ChartJS show vertical line and horizontal on hover tooltip

Tags: javascript, angular, tooltip, chart.js

There is simply way to do show cross line (horizontal and vertical) during hover or on click on point with chartjs ? Exactly like the picture on the snippet.
Before try to do it with the plugin annotation I would like to know if there any way to do that natively.

Thx

```html
<a href="https://ibb.co/hMTGab"><img src="https://preview.ibb.co/c57ngG/chartjs_Tooltip.jpg" alt="chartjs_Tooltip" border="0"></a><br /><a target='_blank' href='https://fr.imgbb.com/'>upload image</a><br />
```

Comment: For those interested by that I made a plugin : https://github.com/ybarbaria/chartjs-plugin-crosshoverline

Comment: I want to do the same thing.......